# Linux - Laptop won't go to suspend/sleep when the lid is closed

Tags: laptop, arch-linux, sleep, power-management, suspend

I recently discovered that my laptop won't go to sleep/suspend once I close my lid and this is actually driving me crazy.

Here is a little information on my machine:

- Kernel: Linux 6.3.1-arch1-1
- Model: Dell Vostro 5620

I run **laptop-mode.service** for power-management, which I'm quite happy with - as I did not find a specific option for the "lid switch" other than:

- ENABLE_LAPTOP_MODE_WHEN_LID_CLOSED=1

Not sure if the below could affect the behavior:

- ENABLE_LAPTOP_MODE_ON_BATTERY=1
- ENABLE_LAPTOP_MODE_ON_AC=1

```
➜  ~ cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf | grep "Switch"

HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
```

I usually use 2 external monitors + my laptop screen and when I close the lid, the two monitors keep working and I can do whatever I want, but clearly I would just like to have the system into suspend/sleep.

Otherwise, if I manually invoke the functionality it would work just fine like:

```
➜  ~ xsecurelock & ; systemctl suspend
```

Looking forward to your advice on this one :)

Comment: Maybe new machine BIOS and Linux power management software?

Comment: @John There is an option in my BIOS to control the lid-switch and that is enabled.